# QueryPerformanceCounter in D?

Tags: d

Is there something (planned) in the D Library to support high precision timers like QueryPerformanceCounter in c++ ? How can I have a portable High precision timer in D ?

Or if it is not available, what would be the *highest* percision timer in D ?

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter is part of winapi. Can't you call winapi functions in D?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

std.datetime has the [StopWatch](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_datetime.html#StopWatch) struct for handling precision timing - and it uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` internally on Windows. On other OSes, it uses whatever the appropriate, high precision monotonic clock is for them.

If what you need is ticks of the system clock rather than a timer specifically, you can call [Clock.currSystemTick](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_datetime.html#currSystemTick) for the current tick of the system clock (or [Clock.currAppTick](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_datetime.html#currAppTick) for the number of system clock ticks since the application started). But `StopWatch` is what you want if you want a timer.